# unable to send or update data into my mysql database using unity

Tags: unity, c#, php

I am trying to save user scores into my data base so i have deveoped backend on php and mysql datbase. All the things are complete but having issues to send or receive data through my unity WWW class.

Here is my C# code to get and send data to php and then DB:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Scripts : MonoBehaviour {
    string dataSubmitURL = "http://localhost/HighScore/AddScore.php?";
    string dataGetURL = "http://localhost/HighScore/GetScore.php";
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        StartCoroutine(GetScores());
        //StartCoroutine(PostScores("faizan",100));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    IEnumerator PostScores(string playerName, int score) {
        string submitURL = dataSubmitURL + "name="+ playerName + "&score=" + score;
        print(submitURL);
        WWW submitData = new WWW(submitURL);
        yield return submitData;
        if (submitData.error != null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Error occur when Submitting data : " + submitData.error);
            Debug.LogError("Error occur when Submitting data : " + submitData.text);
            Debug.LogError("Error occur when Submitting data : " + submitData.responseHeaders);
            //submitData.text
        }
        else {
            print(" Submitted");
        }
    }

    IEnumerator GetScores() {
        WWW getData = new WWW(dataGetURL);
        yield return getData;
        if (getData.error != null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("There was an error getting the high score: " + getData.error);
        }
        else {
            print(getData.text);
        }
    }
}
```

If i directly run my urls into browser

```
string dataGetURL = "http://localhost/HighScore/GetScore.php";
```

then it is working perfectly and giving me data but same thing when i trying through my c# www(above code) then it reply.

```
There was an error getting the high score: Empty reply from server
```

Comment: I may be off, but I don't think you want `yield return getData`.  I believe you should just be using `yield getData`.

Comment: it is not possible to not write return

Comment: What version of Unity are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just change local host to my IP address and it works

```
 string dataSubmitURL = "http://Your IP Address /HighScore/AddScore.php?";
    string dataGetURL = "http://Your IP Address /HighScore/GetScore.php";
```